# Como melhorar minha paginação em php

Tags: php, html, paginação

Oi, eu escrevi uma paginação em php a algum tempo atrás agora tenho um problema com ele essa paginação é simples divide o total de linhas do banco de dados pela quantia de links por pagina; só que agora a quantia de linhas do meu banco de dados cresceu e a paginação esta deformando minha pagina, gostaria de mudar ela colocando um limite exp:

pagina 1, pagina 2 e assim por diante

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ... 56

como eu posso faser isso?

semelhante a paginação do google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia usar um plugin para paginação, como por exemplo, o [pagination.js](http://pagination.js.org/).

Um pequeno exemplo de uso, tirado da [documentação](http://pagination.js.org/docs/index.html), seria assim:

```
$('#demo').pagination({
    dataSource: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... , 195],
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        // template method of yourself
        var html = template(data);
        dataContainer.html(html);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o @Juven_v disse a cima você pode optar por uma biblioteca Javascript para paginar. Mas como a sua tag esta em PHP a solução seria implementar uma paginação utilizando o LIMIT do banco de dados. E outra logica para controlar o total da paginação dependendo da pagina atual do usuário.

Exemplo:
Inicialmente poderia mostrar assim 1, 2, 3 ,4 ............ 49, 48, 50 e ir alterando de acordo com a pagina atual.